# Is it possible to display users that liked Facebook Page?? (similar to like box)

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-page

Just looking for clarification : (I'm not too familiar with the Facebook API)

I want to **display all the users that have liked a specific `Facebook Page` similiar to the `Facebook Like Box`.** Many questions tend to say that information about user likes cannot be obtained due to "privacy reasons".

I know you can get the like count for `videos, photos, etc..` but am unsure about `Pages`.

**I want to verify : Is it possible to get `Facebook Individual User Likes (Page)` with or without authentication?**

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887748/need-some-clarity-on-getting-access-token-detailed-information-from-facebook-p ?

Comment: @MathieuImbert this one actually got a useful answer

Comment: What do you think the difference is between a 'Facebook Page' and a 'Facebook Fan Page'?

Comment: @Igy My mistake, I thought there was a minor difference

Comment: @Igy I'm starting to see you answer all the `facebook` questions. Do you know of any way to indirectly access a `users likes` and see if my page is there. Would this violate facebooks policys (i figure you would know since you work there) Thanks

Comment: indirectly? no. Via the API, with their permission (`user_likes` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) or where their likes are publi), yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use FQL (Facebook Query Language) with the following query:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = YOUR_PAGE_ID_HERE
```

**FQL Reference**: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

**FQL Explorer**: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: @Igy what does it need to be? `object_id` ?

Comment: No, you can't search for a list of users that like a page - only the list of pages that a user likes, or if a specific user (who is using your app) likes a page